# How can I write better code for this condition?

Tags: php

I want to avoid using to nested `if` statements

```
if (! is_null($user)){
    if($user->id == $currentUser->id){
       echo 'its for me';
    }else{
        echo 'its not for me';
    }
}else{
    echo 'its not for me';
}
```

And please note I do not want to use `return` statements

Comment: Use an AND in your if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

isset function and === operator makes it better.

```
 if (isset($user) && $user->id === $currentUser->id) {

    echo 'its for me';

 } else {

    echo 'its not for me';
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: The second condition in the `if` statement doesn't run once the first one is false.. I never realized that thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like this if the else in both cases it's the same.

```
if (!is_null($user) && $user->id == $currentUser->id){
    echo 'its for me';
} else {
    echo 'its not for me';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo 'Its' . (!is_null($user) && $user->id == $currentUser->id ? ' ' : ' not') . ' for me';`

The ternary operator can make if/else clauses very short in certain conditions.